# Incompatible dimensions when trying to use an array of functions within Region3D function

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, regions, list-manipulation

When trying to plot an array of functions within the region3D function, I get the error code

```
Incompatible dimensions of objects at positions {2, 1} and {2, 2} of \
MapThread[Charting`CheckVarSpecPlot[{Visualization`Core`RegionPlot3D,#\
1},{x,-30,30},{y,-30,30},{z,-30,30},
```

I believe this is because, when defining the functions within the array initially, they are defined as standard variables - thus, the region3D function sees them as incompatible with its spatial variables. Is there a way around this or a better way to define an array of functions? My full code is below:

```
min = 700;
max = 800;
n = 0;
layerArray = {};
While [n < 7, 
 AppendTo[layerArray, min <= x^2 + z^2 <= max && y >= -2 && y <= 0]; 
 min = min - 100; max = max - 100;
 n++]
RegionPlot3D[layerArray, {x, -30, 30}, {y, -30, 30}, {z, -30, 30}, 
 PlotPoints -> 60]
```

Comment: `Evaluate` the argument, i.e., `RegionPlot3D[
 Evaluate@layerArray, {x, -30, 30}, {y, -30, 30}, {z, -30, 30}, PlotPoints -> 60]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegionPlot has the attribute HoldAll. You need Evaluate:

```
RegionPlot3D[
 Evaluate@layerArray, {x, -30, 30}, {y, -30, 30}, {z, -30, 30}, 
 PlotPoints -> 60]
```

[image]